# Sqlalchemy Combine 2 queries into single query from the same table on a common column

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I would like to combine 2 queries into one: qa and qs.  Each query on its own gives the correct result when summing columns.  When the two are combined the summed columns are not adding up correctly.  I have tried several ways of grouping and using func.sum

One query is for quantity available:

```
qa = Alltitles.query.join(Partnames, Partnames.id == Alltitles.partname_id) \
            .join(Modelnumbers, Modelnumbers.id == Alltitles.modelnumber_id) \
            .add_columns(Modelnumbers.modelnumber,
                         Partnames.partname,
                         func.sum(Alltitles.quantityavailable - Alltitles.quantitysold))\
            .group_by(Alltitles.modelnumber_id, Alltitles.partname_id)\
            .order_by(Modelnumbers.modelnumber, Partnames.partname)
```

Sample output row:

```
qa: (<Alltitles 486501>, 'H737Q2', 'Resistor', 6) # correct quantity available
```

The other query is for quantity sold:

```
qs = Alltitles.query.join(Partnames, Partnames.id == Alltitles.partname_id) \
        .join(Modelnumbers, Modelnumbers.id == Alltitles.modelnumber_id) \
        .outerjoin(Allsoldrecords, Allsoldrecords.title_id == Alltitles.id) \
        .add_columns(Modelnumbers.modelnumber,
                     Partnames.partname,
                     func.sum(Allsoldrecords.quantity))\
        .group_by(Alltitles.modelnumber_id, Alltitles.partname_id)\
        .order_by(Modelnumbers.modelnumber, Partnames.partname)
```

Sample output row:

```
qs: (<Alltitles 486364>, 'H737Q2', 'Resistor', 16)  # correct quantity sold
```

To combine the two I have tried::

```
qaqs = Alltitles.query.join(Partnames, Partnames.id ==Alltitles.partname_id) \
            .join(Modelnumbers, Modelnumbers.id == Alltitles.modelnumber_id) \
            .join(Allsoldrecords, Allsoldrecords.title_id == Alltitles.id)\
            .add_columns(Modelnumbers.modelnumber,
                         Partnames.partname,
                         func.sum(Alltitles.quantityavailable),
                         func.sum(Alltitles.quantitysold),
                         (Alltitles.quantityavailable - Alltitles.quantitysold),
                         func.sum(Allsoldrecords.quantity))\
            .group_by(Alltitles.modelnumber_id, Alltitles.partname_id)\
            .order_by(Modelnumbers.modelnumber, Partnames.partname)
```

Sample output row:

```
both (<Alltitles 486364>, 'H737Q2', 'Resistor', 85, 72, 13, 16)
```

Using:

```
func.sum(Alltitles.quantityavailable),
                                 func.sum(Alltitles.quantitysold),
```

Sample output row:

```
both: (<Alltitles 486364>, 'H737Q2', 'Resistor', 11, 8, 3, 16)
```

Using:

```
Alltitles.quantityavailable,
                         Alltitles.quantitysold,
```

Combining the two queries to 'qaqs' yields incorrect results for Alltitles.quantityavailable and Alltitles.quantitysold, but are correct in the queries 'qa' and 'qs'. What is the best solution here?

Comment: The modelnumber is the same but the row entry in the alltitles column is different.  These queries are supposed to aggregate all of the modelnumbers+partnames in the alltitles table.

Comment: In last query, please add `func.sum(Alltitles.quantityavailable - Alltitles.quantitysold)` to `add_colums` and reports its output.